# Random RedisConnectionException with Spring reactive redis StreamReceiver

Tags: spring-webflux

I have implemented Spring data Redis StreamReceiver to consume messages. This works fine with standalone Redis but with cluster nodes and connectivity through Spring Redis properties configured like below.

```
spring:
  redis:
    timeout: 3000
    lettuce:
      cluster:
        refresh:
          adaptive: true
          period: 5m
```

But we are observing that the Flux stream closes prematurely sometimes and doesn't listen to new messages any more and the flux terminates prematurely. Sample code we use is shown below.

```
        StreamReceiver<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> receiver = StreamReceiver.create(connectionFactory);
        return reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForStream().createGroup("stream001", "consumer001")
                .thenMany(receiver.receive(Consumer.from(consumerGroup, getConsumerName()),
                                                StreamOffset.create(stream, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()))
                        .onErrorContinue((err, obj) -> {
                            log.error("Continue on error in receiver.receive()", err);
                        })
                        .doOnCancel(() -> {
                            log.error("Stream receiver flux cancelled");
                        }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                            log.error("Stream receiver flux completed");
                        }).doOnError(err -> {
                            log.error("Stream receiver flux on error: ", err);
                        }).doOnTerminate(() -> {
                            log.error("Stream receiver flux on Termination");
                        })
                );
```

We want to debug further as we happened to better use the reactive push standards. We tried with adding the adaptiveRefresh and refreshPeriod props mentioned but its not solving the issue.

We are also evaluating to reinstantiate the Stream Listener so that the connection gets refreshed.

Eception we face

```
 2020-08-30 16:38:54.955 [lettuce-epollEventLoop-4-2] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
  reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionExceptio     n: Unable to connect to 10.123.34.38:6379
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.123.34.38:6379
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
          at io.lettuce.core.cluster.PooledClusterConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnectionAsync$6(PooledClusterConnectionProvider.java:38     4)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
          at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
          at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$initializeChannelAsync0$4(AbstractRedisClient.java:329)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
          at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:577)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
          at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
          at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
          at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to /10.123.34.38:6379
          at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionxception.java:78)
          at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
          ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might land up here, posting the approach used for solving it. No message lag also noticed here. But multiple connection issue observed in few micro secs which happened to be acceptable in our application.

```
        redisStreamMsgs.doOnNext(req -> {
            CopyRequest copyRequest = req.getCopyRequest();
            log.info("Picked from Stream the message for RequestId {}", req.getId());

            // Process our business reactive logiccs
            businessService.performAction(req);

        }).onErrorContinue((throwable, obj) -> {
            log.error("Error while processing the Message ID {}", obj.getClass().getName(), throwable);
        }).doOnSubscribe(msg -> log.error("Message flux Subscribed ")
        ).doOnError(fluxErr -> log.error("Message flux error: ", fluxErr)
        ).doOnComplete(() -> log.error("Messages flux completed for configured")
        ).doOnTerminate(() -> {
            log.info("CopyContext StreamMessages flux terminated ");
            if (!this.beingDestroyed) {
                log.error("Unexpected stream flux termination");
                beansReloaderService.reinitRedisStream().subscribe();
            } else {
                log.info("Normal receiver flux termination due to shutdown");
            }
        }).doFinally(signal -> {
            if(ON_ERROR.equalsIgnoreCase(signal.toString()))
                health.setStreamListenerStatus(false);
        }).subscribe();
```

I happened to beansReloaderService.reinitRedisStream() as below. As a safety, we made health down on the instance if the same issue persists

```
    public Mono<Long> reinitRedisStream() {
        return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(200L)).doOnTerminate(() -> {
            try {
                ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf = configContext.getBeanFactory();

            bf.destroyBean(bf.getBean(Constants.STREAM_LISTENER));
                bf.destroyBean(bf.getBean(Constants.LISTENER_FACTORY));

                bf.createBean(RedisListenFactory.class);
                bf.createBean(RedisStreamListener.class);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Exception occurred when reloading stream beans", ex);
            }
        });
```